# Getting the first 3 letters of the value entered from Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two inputs. I want to show the first 3 letters of the value entered from the first input in the input below. How can I do ?

```
<input type="text" name="firstinput" required placeholder="First Input"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="secondinput" required placeholder="Second Input">
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far and what you have tried.

Comment: @CalIrvine I showed

Comment: Also add the js/jquery you tried to use that isn't working properly.

Comment: @justDan I tried it with Javascript but I couldn't

Comment: So post the js in your question for others to see.

Comment: Check the answer below

Comment: I actually tagged Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the substring() js function for this

Using pure javascript:

```js
document.getElementById("firstinput").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
   var name = document.getElementById("firstinput").value;
   name = name.substring(0,3);
   document.getElementById("secondinput").value = name;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="firstinput" name="firstinput" required placeholder="First Input"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="secondinput" name="secondinput" required placeholder="Second Input">
```

Using jquery:

```js
$("#firstinput").keyup(function(){
  var fname = $("#firstinput").val().substring(0, 3);
  $("#secondinput").val(fname); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="firstinput" name="firstinput" required placeholder="First Input"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="secondinput" name="secondinput" required placeholder="Second Input">
```

Comment: Yeah, I want something like this, but it's not. I want to print that 3 letters to the second input instead of printing to the command line

Comment: Okay making changes

Comment: Yes it is. But is it possible to do it directly without clicking the button?

Comment: I can't use Javascript well. So can you do it?

Comment: Yes i have made changes in answer, do mark it correct answer